# Integration by parts vs u-substitution

Tags: calculus

This is something that is confusing the heck out of me. In calculus we progressively learned definite integrals, indefinite integrals, u-substitution of integrals, and now integration by parts.

So the confusion lies here.

In the u-substitution section of our textbook it has several problems to solve like these:

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}$ cos$(6x)$sin$($sin$(6x))dx$

$\int_{0}^{1} x^{35}e^{-x^{36}}$

From what I have read and been taught, integration by parts corresponds to the product rule for differentiation $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)g(x)]=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)$

Are these not functions multiplied by other functions hence integration by parts should be used? The reason I am asking is because they not integrated this way in the solutions part of the textbook.

Comment: Just because integration by parts *could* be used doesn't mean it *should* be used.

Comment: Just because two functions are multiplied doesn't mean IBP is the best way to go.

Comment: I see, and I kind of thought that when integrating the above using the product rule, it was a tad messy. So how would you "differentiate" (pun intended) between when/not to use integration by parts.

Comment: This lies in recognizing the forms of the integrand. For substitution, you need to have a function and its derivative, perhaps off by a factor. Can you see how it's used here?

Comment: Also, with derivatives, there does not seem to be this openness between choosing to use the chain rule or product rule. It's just what you do when you have an inside and outside function (chain rule) and when you have function times a function then product rule.

Comment: @Sean Roberson: Ah I see, thank you that helps.

Comment: Note that $u$ substitution also involves a product, since the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is the product $g'(x)f'(g(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral is easily computed with the substitution $u=\sin 6x$. Integrating that thing by parts could be a nightmare.

Same thing with the second integral. $u=x^{36}$ Would be a great choice, while integrating by parts probably won't get anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! I see the logic now.

Comment: @user583753  PS: Notice the periodicity of the trig functions.  This is a clue that that integral over that interval **may** equal *zero*.  So *test* for that by first substituting $u:=2\pi-x$ and seeing if indeed, $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)~\mathsf dx = -\int_0^{2\pi} f(u)~\mathsf d u$

Comment: You're very welcome :) When it comes to integration, a lot of the time, the easiest way is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you learn the method of integration by parts, you don't have to apply it to every integral.

Your examples are in the form of $$\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx$$ where you can solve the integral by substitution $$ u=g(x)$$ and $$du= g'(x)dx$$

There  is no need for integration by parts because you can easily solve $$\int f(u)du$$

If you insist in solving these integrals by integration by parts you may let $$u=1, dv=f(g(x))g'(x)dx$$ which gives you $$uv-\int vdu =v=\int f(g(x)g'(x)dx$$ which takes you back to your original integral.

If you pick a different $u$ and $dv$ you may get a more complicated integral than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I was able to understand that you are having trouble whether to use the substitution method or integration by parts.

Here's an easy method for using by-parts:

$$  \int f(x)\cdot g(x) dx = f(x) ( \int g(x) dx)-\int   (f^{'}(x) \cdot (\int g(x) dx) dx  ) $$

Always remember that $f(x)$ is our first function and $g(x)$ is our second function. So how do we decide the first function and second function?

Remember the rule ILATE:

```
I - Inverse Trigonometric functions
L - Logarithmic function
A - Algebraic
T - Trigonometric functions
E - Exponential function
```

Where the first written have higher priority.

Only use by parts when you don't see any relation like in: (writing randomly)

$$ \int sin(x) \cdot \ln{x} dx  $$

But there's no need in

$$ \int x \cdot \ln{x} dx $$

Here the substitution $x=e^{u}$ works perfectly.